# symfony assert for entity type variable

Tags: forms, symfony

how validate entity variable, because in my point it's valid for empty select.

```
 /**
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message = "education level cannot be empty")
 * @var EducationLevel[]|ArrayCollection
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\EducationLevel")
 */
private $educationLevel;
```

form type

```
->add('educationLevel', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => 'AppBundle:EducationLevel',
            'multiple' => true,
            'choice_label' => function ($educationLevel) {
                return $educationLevel->getName();
            },
        ])
```

Answer (score 0):

NotBlank won't work, because it checks if value is not null or not empty string or not false
[NotBlank manual](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/NotBlank.html)

What you have to do is to write custom Constraint and a validator:

[Custom validator manual](http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html)

Answer (score -2):

You can create a validation method in the entity which can verify if $educationLevel is null or collection of EducationLevel instances.

```
/**
 * @Assert\IsTrue(message="Education level has to be blank or...")
 */
public function isEducationLevelValid()
{
    if ($this->educationLevel->isEmpty()) {
        foreach ($this->educationLevel as $edulevel) {
            if (!$edulevel instanceof EducationLevel) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The method is used automatically during entity bound form submission and of course you can use it as a normal entity's method.

Comment: thanks, this assert work, but it work always, when education lvl empty and than not empty : )

Comment: i must this line * @Assert\IsTrue(message="Education level has to be blank") add near my function who check or valid and near variable educationLevel?

Comment: i resolve this problem need check with method in arrayCollection isEmpty()

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your original question correctly - I thought you want valid state in case of $educationLevel is null or contains collection of educationLevel instances. Updated my answer.

Comment: We shouln't add any logic to entites. It's not the right place to be. See my answer, if you still cannot manage it, I can help you more. Validators are for validation :)